# Imagemagick & php prevent text output while using convert

Tags: php, imagemagick

Hi: I am using these commands to compare colors, it works however it prints text that I do not want to be printed:

```
$color2= system("/usr/bin/convert xc:'#".$color2."' -format '%[pixel:s]' info:");
$result= system("/usr/bin/convert xc:'".$color."' -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz ".$fuzz." -fill '".$color2."' -opaque '".$color2."' -format '%[pixel:s]' info:");
```

outputs:

```
 red grey20 rgb(238,0,0) grey20 rgb(221,0,0) grey20 rgb(204,0,0) grey20 rgb(187,0,0) grey20 rgb(170,0,0) grey20 rgb(153,0,0) grey20 rgb(136,0,0) grey20 rgb(119,0,0) grey20 rgb(102,0,0) grey20 rgb(85,0,0) grey20 rgb(68,0,0) grey20 rgb(51,0,0) grey20 rgb(204,51,51) grey20 rgb(153,51,51) grey20 rgb(204,102,102) grey20 rgb(204,0,51) grey20 lime grey20 rgb(0,238,0) grey20 rgb(0,221,0) grey20 rgb(0,204,0) grey20 rgb(0,187,0) grey20 rgb(0,170,0) grey20 rgb(0,153,0) grey20 rgb(0,136,0) grey20 rgb(0,119,0) grey20 rgb(0,102,0) grey20 rgb(0,85,0) grey20 rgb(0,68,0) grey20 rgb(0,51,0) grey20 blue grey20 rgb(0,0,238) grey20 rgb(0,0,221) grey20 rgb(0,0,204) grey20 rgb(0,0,187) grey20 rgb(0,0,170) grey20 rgb(0,0,153) grey20 rgb(0,0,136) grey20 rgb(0,0,119) grey20 rgb(0,0,102) grey20 rgb(0,0,85) grey20 rgb(0,0,68) grey20 rgb(0,0,51) grey20 rgb(0,127,255) grey20 rgb(51,51,102) grey20 cyan grey20 rgb(153,204,255) grey20 rgb(127,0,255) grey20 rgb(102,45,145) grey20 rgb(255,0,127) grey20 rgb(244,154,193) grey20 yellow grey20 rgb(255,127,0) grey20 rgb(247,148,29) grey20 rgb(96,58,32) grey20 rgb(117,76,36) grey20 black grey20 grey20 grey20
```

How do I prevent that text from being dispalyed?

Comment: Can you tell us the text you _do_ want printed? Then we can come up with answers that don't tell you to just put ` > /dev/null` at the end of the line ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.system.php -> set the return var value, so the output is placed there instead of printed out

Comment: Hi, I tried but output is "red black" and the script no longers works... system("/usr/bin/convert xc:'#".$color."' -format '%[pixel:s]' info:",$color2);
          system("/usr/bin/convert xc:'".$color."' -alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz ".$fuzz." -fill '".$color2."' -opaque '".$color2."' -format '%[pixel:s]' info:",$result);

Comment: Hi, the "&" in front of the parameter means that you pass a pointer to the method invocation:
$myOutput = '';
system('your_stuff', &$myOutput);
echo $myOutput;

Comment: I have added the & infront of the variables and I still get the same output

Comment: Maybe you should try passthru()
"The system() call also tries to automatically flush the web server's output buffer after each line of output if PHP is running as a server module. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function."

Comment: Hey, the passthru function did not work either, however I tried exec() and it works without outputting the data. Thanks!